# How do i fetch session id from database to controller and compare codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

It Return undefined index uname also try $row->name not working return false

```
  public function profile() {
            $this->load->view('header');
            $uname = $this->session->userdata('uname');
            $row = $this->brid_groom_fetch->get_program_specific_gender();
            if ($row['uname']->uname == $uname) {
                $session_id = $this->session->userdata('session_id');
                var_dump($session_id);
            } else {
                echo 'fail';
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to assign session variables to an array.
Then your code

```
$id = $this->session->userdata('uname')
```

will be relevent.
To assign you can use

```
$this->session->set_userdata(
                              array(
                                     'uname' => $row->name
                                    )
                            );
```

Where $row->name is the value fetched from your model query.

The above sets the value in session variable 'uname'

Now you can use $id wherever you want

Also Check your autoload.php file under config dir

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('session');
```

should be present there.

If not, then you can do the above or call

```
$this->load->library('session')
```

in your controller function.

See if that helps

Comment: I have add this code but it is not working plz give solution

Comment: I have edited the answer to provide more information. Please check with these and see. If problem persists, provide your controller function where login happens to inspect more in details after the changes done